# A query to do something like an outer join between two arrays in the same document

Tags: mongodb

Given the following collection structure:

```
db.two_lists.insert(
{
    "addresses":[
        {
            "studentId":1111,
            "addr":"1234 N Oak St.",
            "city":"Chicago",
            "state":"IL",
            "zipcode":60601
        },
                {
            "studentId":3333,
            "addr":"1234 N Oak St.",
            "city":"Chicago",
            "state":"IL",
            "zipcode":60601
        }
    ],
    "students":[
        {
            "id":1111,
            "name":'Frank Smith'
        },
        {
            "id":2222,
            "name":'Joe Smith'
        }
    ]
}
);
```

I'm trying to return a list of students and their corresponding addresses. The problem is those two are stored in separate arrays. I need to match them up by studentId. I found a way to do that:

```
db.two_lists.aggregate([
    {$match:{}}
    ,{$unwind:"$students"}
    ,{$unwind:"$addresses"}
    ,{$project:{ addresses:1, students:1,
        sameId : {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$addresses.studentId", '$students.id' ] }, then: true, else: false }}}
    }
    ,{$match:{sameId:true}}
]);
```

Unfortunately my query eliminates students w/o addresses (studentId:2222). How to best deal with a problem like that. Changing collection structure is not an option.

Expected output

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("567b6f3aba874c0b52280d49"),
            "addresses" : {
                "studentId" : 1111,
                "addr" : "1234 N Oak St.",
                "city" : "Chicago",
                "state" : "IL",
                "zipcode" : 60601
            },
            "students" : {
                "id" : 1111,
                "name" : "Frank Smith"
            }
        },
        {
            "students" : {
                "id" : 2222,
                "name" : "Joe Smith"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Nice to see the insert scripts posted as part of the problem. Can you please post an expected output structure, it would speak immense.

Comment: The problem is the data model in general. Simply create a document per student, together with his address and Bob's your uncle: no BSON size limit, no needlessly complicated queries.

Comment: @BatScream Just added the output I want.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Agreed, but like I already stated, changing it is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
db.two_lists.aggregate([
    {$match:{}}
    ,{$unwind:"$students"}
    ,{$unwind:"$addresses"}
    ,{$project:{ students:1,
        addresses : {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$addresses.studentId", "$students.id" ] }, then: "$addresses", else: null }}}
    }
    ,{$group:{_id:{students:"$students"}, addresses:{$addToSet:"$addresses"}}}
]);
```

Gives me pretty much the result I was looking for:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "students" : {
                    "id" : 2222,
                    "name" : "Joe Smith"
                }
            },
            "addresses" : [ 
                null
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "students" : {
                    "id" : 1111,
                    "name" : "Frank Smith"
                }
            },
            "addresses" : [ 
                null, 
                {
                    "studentId" : 1111,
                    "addr" : "1234 N Oak St.",
                    "city" : "Chicago",
                    "state" : "IL",
                    "zipcode" : 60601
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```